# Responsive Web Typography (for line-height calculation in ems) Code Explanation Needed

Tags: web, typography, css

I am attempting to understand the CSS calculation process that went into the following CSS stylings. The code comes from a responsive Wordpress theme, and I cannot figure out how the author arrived at the em values for the line-heights of the `<h>` elements. I have went through the following tutorial at [here.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/14/technical-web-typography-guidelines-and-techniques/)

The tutorial was very helpful, but I cannot see how the author of the code presented below arrived at his/her numbers. If someone could explain the formula and process this author used, I would be greatly appreciative. It appears that 14px is the base font-size and 22px is the base margin which produced the base leading of 1.57142857 (22 / 14 = 1.57142857). Beyond that, I cannot see the reasoning for the author's line-height values for the  elements.

```
body { font:normal 14px/1.57142857 Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, 
p, blockquote, pre, address,
dl, ol, ul, table,
legend, hr, figure {    
margin-bottom:22px;
}

li > ul,
li > ol {
margin-bottom:0; 
}

/* Headings */
h1, .h1 { font-size:60px; line-height:1.10000000; font-weight:normal;  }
h2, .h2 { font-size:36px; line-height:1.16666667; font-weight:normal;  }  
h3, .h3 { font-size:24px; line-height:1.25000000; font-weight:normal;  }
h4, .h4 { font-size:18px; line-height:1.33333333; font-weight:normal; }
h5, .h5 { font-size:14px; line-height:1.57142857; font-weight:normal; }
h6, .h6 { font-size:12px; line-height:1.57142857; font-weight:normal; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The author must have used a [modular scale.](http://modularscale.com/)

Check the [description](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/typography.php) of how it's being used by the Zurb's Foundation framework.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will follow your suggested links and try to piece it together. The values seem too precise to be arbitrary.